# 'Exec format error' when cross-compiling with Bazel (TensorFlow)

Tags: c++, tensorflow, arm, cross-compiling, bazel

I'm cross-compiling a big Bazel-based project (TensorFlow) with a custom C++ toolchain as per [this tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html). The compilation chugs along nicely for a while, until I eventually get

`/bin/bash: bazel-out/host/bin/path/to/file: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

The binary file in question varies (so this appears to be a general problem of my cross-compiling configuration) but one thing is always the same; the binary was compiled for my ARM-based target platform (as you would expect). Now the problem of course is that Bazel tries to execute that binary on my x86-64 host platform, which logically fails.

Also, regardless of the specific binary that fails, the following line appears at the end of the error message:

`Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform`

This may be helpful in finding the solution to you Bazel experts out there kind enough to assist and read (thank you!), but a search for `@local_execution_config_platform//:platform` inside the entire project directory yields one single unhelpful (to me) result (also it seems to be related to TensorFlow specifically, so I find the lack of search results even odder). Of course I can provide more details on this - or on anything else - if you ask.

My toolchain configuration follows Bazel's own tutorial, as I said. My question is: What is the right way to handle cross-compiling scenarios with Bazel such that this error does not happen? Do I need to wholly suppress the execution of these binaries after they've been built, and if so, how would I go about achieving this?

P.S.: For the record, the target I'm building is `//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so`.

P.P.S.: There is a binary for which I get a different error, namely `bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`. However, I assume the underlying issue is the same as this is also an ARM binary that Bazel tries to execute on my x86-64 system.